# rabbitmq with multiple symfony2 applications on one server

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

I developed a `Symfony2` web application with `RabbitMqBundle` and it's working fine.

Now I'm trying to set up more instances of the same application for other developers. So, now I have 9 instances (dev01 - dev09). I've created the databases and set up files for each dev instance and they are working fine, except `RabbitMq`. For example, a message queue created by `dev01`, but it was processed by a consumer of dev02 (it should be processed by dev01) and so on.

I think I need to configure connections/producers/consumers for our multiple applications but I don't know where to start.

**[Updated on Jan 23 at 4 AM EST]**
For a try, I changed the name in the queue_options to 'api.import.dev01'. However it got the following error even though I'm specifying the callback "wl.api.import.consumer":

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException] You have requested a non-existent service "old_sound_rabbit_mq.api.import.dev01_consumer".
```

Could anyone give me some directions (e.g. links to examples or documentations)?

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
 connections:
  default:
   host:"%mq.default.host%"
   port:"%mq.default.port%"
   user:"%mq.default.user%"
   password:"%mq.default.pass%"
   vhost:"%mq.default.vhost%"
   lazy:"%mq.default.lazy%"
 producers:
  event:
   connection:  default
   exchange_options: { name: 'event', type: topic }
   auto_setup_fabric: false
 consumers:
  api.import:
   connection: default
   exchange_options:
    name: 'event'
    type: topic
   queue_options:
    name: 'api.import'
    routing_keys:
     - 'api.import.#'
   callback: wl.api.import.consumer
   qos_options: { prefetch_size: 0, prefetch_count: 100, global: false }
   auto_setup_fabric: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Same like you are using separate instances of the database, you can create separate queues.

Comment: I'm asking how.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to configure a rabbitmq vhost per application?

https://www.rabbitmq.com/vhosts.html